# Regex source generator with large regex causes OutOfMemoryException at dotnet build

Tags: .net, c#-11.0, .net-7.0

I have a large regex in the form of a word list separated by `|`. The entire regex length is 1 million characters

```cs
[RegexGenerator(@"KnownItem1|KnownItem2|KnownItem3")]
private static partial Regex NamedEntities();
```

Building with dotnet build results in this error

```
CSC : warning CS8785: Generator 'RegexGenerator' failed to generate source. It will not contribute to the output and co
mpilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'OutOfMemoryException' with message 'Exception of type 'S
ystem.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'
```

The dotnet.exe process took up 5GB of RAM when the above error is encountered. How can I get the build to succeed?

I had searched for how to increase RAM used by dotnet build, how to reduce RAM usage by not emitting debug symbols, but did not find a solution. This is also a different case compared to Regex OOM at runtime which has been asked many times on StackOverflow -- this is a compile time error with the new Regex source generator. This regex works in interpreted mode at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET regex is not optimized for this use case currently. There is [discussion about optimizing for this case with Aho-Corasick](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62447).

The workaround now is to use Aho-Corasick and eliminate overlapping matches manually.

E.g.

`hellover` when matched on regex `hello|lover` matches `hello`.

However, Aho-Corasick matches both `hello` and `lover`, thus you'll have to keep track of the indices and lengths of the matches returned and eliminate `lover` in order to mimic the regex behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You should *really* not be using the regex source generator for that matter. Using the regex source generator takes regular expressions and transforms them into written code that then gets compiled alongside your project in the same assembly. It is preferred to use when you're trying to avoid slow startups of the regex engine when you're asking it to match using a given regex.

However, there is the [`RegexOptions.Compiled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions-compiled) option that tells the engine to compile that expression into a separate assembly (in more or less the same way as the source generator). This delegates the compilation process of the regex at runtime, rather than compile-time. The objective of that option is to avoid runtime interpretation of the regex, and hard-code it into a method that performs better.

### TL;DR

For too large regex (about 500 chars is large) use [`RegexOptions.Compiled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions-compiled). For smaller ones, prefer the source generator.